How can I get traceId in a Firebase cloud function?
I would like to propagate traceId between a couple microservices in Firebase/GCP by 1) getting the traceId from the root service, and 2) propagating it using "x-cloud-trace-context" in the header of the API call for the second. Part two is working fine for me, but I can't get the traceId of the root service for the life of me.
The function is defined in this style through firebase (using Pub/Sub, Scheduler, etc):
export const foobar = functions.region(REGION).runWith({ memory: '2GB' }).pubsub.schedule('*/15 * * * *').onRun(async (context) => { ...function }

I have tried @google-cloud/trace-agent, @opencensus/propagation-tracecontext, @opentelemetry/api, etc with no luck in extracting a traceId from the root (foobar in this example). When I look at GCP Logs Explorer I see that there is a traceId, so I'd be thrilled to be able to extract that, or even overwrite that traceId with one that I make myself.
I tried this with GCP Trace-Agent, but the contexts came out null
TraceAgent.start()
const tracer = TraceAgent.get()
const span = tracer.getCurrentRootSpan()
const childSpan = tracer.createChildSpan({ name: 'new-span' })
console.log(span.getTraceContext())
console.log(childSpan.getTraceContext())

Also tried similar calls with the other packages I mentioned.
I inspected the context passed from PubSub but there was no useful information in that
Any help would be much appreciated. Thx.

I'm not sure this is possible, but the Firebase Functions SDK seems to use its own Trace implementation for V2 cloud functions.

Ok, worked it out. Unfortunately the only way I could solve this was using the deprecated function process._getActiveHandles(). This will return active handles such as the open http request presumably opened by GCP Cloud Functions. In there you can get the headers which include the x-cloud-trace-context and traceparent.
Something like this should work:
function findTraceId() {
    const activeHandles = process._getActiveHandles()
    for (const handle of activeHandles) {
        const headers = handle?._httpMessage?.req?.rawHeaders
        const traceIdIndex = headers.indexOf('X-Cloud-Trace-Context')
        return headers[traceIdIndex + 1].split('/')[0]
    }
}

